# Are the staples used to tag wood at the DIY store saw safe?

Tags: table-saw, foreign-object

The current trend at my local DIY stores is to staple a tag to the butt of the wood for pricing.  I usually pull these out by sliding the tip of a screw driver between the wood and the staple and pulling it out, "usually" being the key word.

I rip a lot of wood to my required size, so once in while the staple is still in wood when it goes through the saw.  Are these staples made to be saw blade safe (like will not harm the blade or ME)?  If not, what is the best tool for removing price staples from the butt of the wood?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well most of the staples are not very long so if you are not just 'nipping the tip' you shouldn't have to worry about them.

However, while they won't do much to a blade, (though I wouldn't say they are 'good' for it) they can be dangerous to you if you are cutting close enough to the edge where the staple might be cut.  In that case it could become a small sharp projectile, so removing it would be a good idea.  I usually use screw drivers and/or pliers.

Comment: My fear is the possibility of them nicking my planer knives, so I always pull them out. My preferred method is pliers as well.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't sound like this is the case for you but staples are an issue if you have a SawStop table saw. With this table saw, if the blade comes in contact with any metal, the stopping mechanism will fire and the blade and brake housing will need to be replaced.

Comment: Not sure that's true if the metal is small and insulated, but better not to risk it... It occurs to me that there ought to be something that will work as a scaled-up version of office staple removers...

Comment: Contact with a staple in wood that's being cut shouldn't trigger the SawStop brake. Here's a [video of a guy cutting through a nail](https://youtu.be/rnlTGndRi38?t=1m54s) without stopping the saw.

Comment: Interesting. I was a member of a woodshop that warned against staples and nails in wood when using their saw stops. They said they had several saw stops activated because of metals in the wood, but I never witnessed it myself.